# Unable to set focus on autocomplete

Tags: kendo-ui

I have an autocomplete inside of a panelBar. When a panelBar is activated, I would like to set the focus to the autoComplete input. I have tried several ways to get this to work, but cannot find a way to do this.

The method is invoked and I can find the autocomplete. However, I am unable to set focus.

```
        //Kendo PanelBar
        function onPanelBarActivate(e) {
            var $autoComplete = $('input .txtProductText', e);

            $autoComplete.focus();
        }
        var $panelBar = $('#panelbar').kendoPanelBar({ expandMode: "single",  expand: onPanelBarActivate }).data("kendoPanelBar");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns empty jQuery object:

```
$('input .txtProductText', e);
```

First `e` is the event argument of the activate event. It cannot be used as the context of jQuery. You should use `e.item` instead. Second 'input .txtProductText' means 'child of an input whose class is txtProductText'. This is probably not what you need since 'input' elements can't really have children.

Try this instead:

```
$('.txtProductText', e.item);
```